# How to create a stream to get http request then use it inside StreamBuilder

Tags: http, flutter, stream, provider

i need to keep track of my data if anything changes in it , and i find StreamBuilder a good fit for my requirements , but i have a problem creating the stream. 
so i need to create a stream to get my data from http request and pass to my stream builder, but i don't know to create that stream

Comment: so you need multiple http requests to get updated data - how do you know that "anything changes" in your data?

Comment: when i used firebase with streambuilder , whenever i change my data , it changes in my app directly , with some digging i found that steambuilder does this work , but my problem with the steam now

Comment: so you are using firebase or making [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) requests?

Comment: now i need to do the same thing but for http requests

Comment: so:  how do you know that "anything changes" in your data? i hope you know that you have to make http request? it is not done automatically?

Comment: yes i know, now i only need to create a stream that get my data that's all , but i dunno how

Comment: check [Creating streams in Dart](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams) then

Comment: i already did that , but i don't get it so well , that's why im asking here

Comment: Please check the guidelines on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask